# URL Rewriting with ExpressJS

Tags: url-rewriting, express

I would like to rewrite my URLs on my ExpressJS website. I've used this plugin, https://github.com/joehewitt/express-rewrite, but it doesn't work...

However, I might have made a mistake...

My app.js file :

```
var express = require('express')
    , index = require('./routes/index.js')
    , admin = require('./routes/admin.js')
    , contact = require('./routes/contact.js')
    , posts = require('./routes/posts.js')
    , http = require('http')
    , path = require('path')
    , hash = require('./auth').hash
    , db = require('./models')
    , favicons = require('connect-favicons')
    , rewriter = require('express-rewrite');


var app = express();

app.configure(function () {
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/images/FAVICON.ico'));
    app.use(favicons(__dirname + '/public/images/apple-touch-icon.png'));
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.cookieSession({
            secret: 'SECRET',
            cookie: { access: false }
        })
    );
    app.use(rewriter);
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(function(req, res, next){
        res.render('404.jade', {
            title: "404 - Page Not Found",
            showFullNav: false,
            status: 404,
            url: req.url
        });
    });
});

app.configure('development', function () {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', index.index);

app.get('/toto', rewriter.rewrite('/heytoto'));

db.sequelize.sync().complete(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        throw err
    } else {
        http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
            console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'))
        })
    }
});
```

My error message :

```
Express
500 TypeError: Object function app(req, res){ app.handle(req, res); } has no method 'match'
at Object.rewriter [as handle] (/Users/anthonycluse/Sites/Anthony-Cluse-Express/node_modules/express-rewrite/rewrite.js:3:26)
at next (/Users/anthonycluse/Sites/Anthony-Cluse-Express/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:199:15)
at Object.cookieSession [as handle] (/Users/anthonycluse/Sites/Anthony-Cluse-Express/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/cookieSession.js:113:5)
at next (/Users/anthonycluse/Sites/Anthony-Cluse-Express/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:199:15)
at Object.cookieParser [as handle] (/Users/anthonycluse/Sites/Anthony-Cluse-Express/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/cookieParser.js:60:5)
at next (/Users/anthonycluse/Sites/Anthony-Cluse-Express/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:199:15)
at resume (/Users/anthonycluse/Sites/Anthony-Cluse-Express/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:60:7)
at SendStream.error (/Users/anthonycluse/Sites/Anthony-Cluse-Express/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:73:37)
at SendStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
at SendStream.error (/Users/anthonycluse/Sites/Anthony-Cluse-Express/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:147:51)
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

So I had sort of the same issue. I wrote an app that uses the history API on browsers and I wanted to rewrite all non-static URLs back to `index.html`. So for static files I did:

```
app.configure(function() {
  app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/'));
});
```

But then for the history API generated paths I did:

```
app.get('*', function(request, response, next) {
  response.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

This meant that any request that wasn't a file or directory in `/` (such as a URL generated by the history API) wouldn't be rewritten or redirected but instead the `index.html` file will be served and that then does all the JS routing magic.

Hopefully that's close to what you're looking for?

Comment: I can't get it work, can help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971489/refresh-specific-page-with-angular-express-and-jade-using-html5mode?noredirect=1#comment44494193_27971489

Comment: what I can do if I need rewrite using regexp ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38117026/expressjs-rewrite-regex

Comment: but due this if hit simple http request that returns json ..... at this time index.html will also be called .so this is not nice solution.

Answer (score 45):

You could rewrite the URL before you get to the handler you want to use.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   if (req.url === '/toto') {
     req.url = '/heytoto';
   }
   next();
});

app.get('/heytoto', ...);
```

I've used a [similar method](https://burgers.io/cache-busting-in-node) to do URL rewrites with regular expressions.

Answer (score 6):

A solution that works without `response.sendfile(..)` is to use a rewrite middleware that is inserted prior to `app.use(express.static(..))` like this:

```
// forward all requests to /s/* to /index.html

app.use(function(req, res, next) {

  if (/\/s\/[^\/]+/.test(req.url)) {
    req.url = '/index.html';
  }

  next();
});

// insert express.static(...)
```

This way, expressjs properly recognizes the rewrite. The `static` middleware will then take care of serving the file.

Answer (score 1):

### 1) Your rewrite middleware must appear before the middleware/function that will handle the request.

Won't work:

```
app.use('/hello', () => sayHello() );
app.use(() => rewriteURLToHello()); //it's too late to try to rewrite a URL to /hello
```

Will work:

```
app.use(() => rewriteURLToHello()); //we can rewrite a URL to /hello
app.use('/hello', () => sayHello() ); //rewritten URL will be handled here
```

### 2) Your middleware must not be bound to the path you're trying to rewrite

Won't work:

```
app.use('/hello', (req, res, next) => {
  //'/hello' has been trimmed from req.url
  //req.url is / if the request was for /hello
  req.url = '/goodbye'; //technically setting full path to /hello/goodbye
  next(); //will only call other middleware in the /hello chain
});
app.use('/goodbye', () => sayBye()); //won't work
```

Will work:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {    //runs for every path. Same as .use('/',
  //'/hello' has NOT been trimmed from req.url
  //req.url is /hello if the request was for /hello
  if (req.url.startsWith('/hello')) { 
    req.url = '/goodbye'; //full path now /goodbye
  }
  next(); //will continue calling all middleware
});
app.use('/goodbye', () => sayBye()); //will work
```

Answer (score 0):

you could check the url with an if condition and use app.redirect to redirect to a certain url.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
app.get('/toto', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/heytoto');
});
```

Comment: Yea but it's a redirection... And I wanna rewrite my urls I don't wanna use the "res.redirect()" function.