# Refresh specific page with Angular, Express and Jade (using html5mode)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, page-refresh

I'm trying to refresh a page and execute client route to open a template inside ng-view

**Index.jade**

```
extends layouts/default

block content
  section(data-ng-view)
  script(type="text/javascript").
    window.user = !{user};
```

**default.jade**

```
doctype html
html(lang='en', xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', xmlns:fb='https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml', itemscope='itemscope', itemtype='http://schema.org/Product')
  include ../includes/head
body
  div(data-ng-include="'static/modules/core/views/core.header.view.html'", data-role="navigation")
  div(data-ng-include="'static/modules/core/views/core.index.view.html'", data-role="navigation")
  div(data-ng-include="'static/modules/core/views/core.menu.view.html'", data-role="navigation")
  div(data-ng-include="'static/modules/core/views/core.footer.view.html'", data-role="navigation")
  include ../includes/foot
```

**Server route**

```
// Camera Routes
    app.get('/api/cameras', cameras.all);
    app.post('/api/cameras', auth.requiresLogin, cameras.create);
    app.get('/api/cameras/:cameraId', cameras.show);
    app.put('/api/cameras/:cameraId', auth.requiresLogin, auth.article.hasAuthorization, cameras.update);
    app.del('/api/cameras/:cameraId', auth.requiresLogin, auth.article.hasAuthorization, cameras.destroy);
    app.param('cameraId', cameras.camera);

    // Home route
    app.get('/', index.render);
```

**express.js**

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var express = require('express');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var helpers = require('view-helpers');
var config = require('./config');

module.exports = function(app, passport) {

    console.log('Initializing Express');

    app.set('showStackError', true);    

    //Prettify HTML
    app.locals.pretty = true;

    //Should be placed before express.static
    app.use(express.compress({
        filter: function(req, res) {
            return (/json|text|javascript|css/).test(res.getHeader('Content-Type'));
        },
        level: 9
    }));

    //Setting the fav icon and static folder
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use('/static',express.static(config.root + '/public'));

    //Don't use logger for test env
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
        app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    }

    //Set views path, template engine and default layout
    app.set('views', config.root + '/app/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');

    //Enable jsonp
    app.enable("jsonp callback");

    app.configure(function() {
        //cookieParser should be above session
        app.use(express.cookieParser());

        // request body parsing middleware should be above methodOverride
        app.use(express.urlencoded());
        app.use(express.json());
        app.use(express.methodOverride());

        //express/mongo session storage
        app.use(express.session({ secret: '$uper$ecret$e$$ionKey'}));

        //connect flash for flash messages
        app.use(flash());

        //dynamic helpers
        app.use(helpers(config.app.name));

        //use passport session
        app.use(passport.initialize());
        app.use(passport.session());

        //routes should be at the last
        app.use(app.router);
        //Assume "not found" in the error msgs is a 404. this is somewhat silly, but valid, you can do whatever you like, set properties, use instanceof etc.

        app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
            res.render('index.jade', {'root': 'app/views/'});
        });

        app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
            //Treat as 404
            if (~err.message.indexOf('not found')) return next();

            //Log it
            console.error(err.stack);

            //Error page
            res.status(500).render('500', {
                error: err.stack
            });
        });

        //Assume 404 since no middleware responded
        app.use(function(req, res, next) {
            res.status(404).render('404', {
                url: req.originalUrl,
                error: 'Not found'
            });
        });
    });
};
```

**HTML5 ENABLE**

```
//Setting HTML5 Location Mode
angular.module('mean').config(['$locationProvider',
    function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix("!");
    }
]);
```

**Client router** here, I want to show this template inside ng-view

```
angular.module('mean').config(['$stateProvider',
function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.
        state('viewCamera', {
            url: "/cameras/:cameraId",
            templateUrl: 'static/modules/cameras/views/cameras.camera.view.html'
        });
}
```

]);

**Index view with ui-view tag**

```
<section data-ng-controller="MapController" data-ng-init="find()">
    <div ui-view>
    </div>
    <div class="map-content" ng-class="{'map-content-left': cameraOpen != undefined}">
        <leaflet defaults="defaults" center="center" class="map"></leaflet>
    </div>
</section>
```

**My html head**

```
head
  base(href='/')
```

What I want? When insert this url manually: localhost:3000/cameras/12, call server and get index to call client route and open the template inside ng-view

What's the problem? When I insert this url in browser, I get the index.jade with download mode

What I already tried?

Change the server route to this (apparently this return rendered index)

```
  // Home route
    app.get('*', index.render);
```

But the client route is never called

What's wrong?

**EDIT 1**

**My dependencies version**

```
"angular": "latest",
"angular-resource": "latest",
"angular-cookies": "latest",
"angular-mocks": "latest",
"angular-ui-utils": "0.0.4",
"angular-translate": "~2.5.2",
"angular-translate-loader-static-files": "~2.5.2",
"ngDialog": "~0.3.7",
"angular-leaflet-directive": "~0.7.10",
"leaflet.markercluster": "~0.4.0",
"angular-loading-bar": "~0.6.0",
"angular-ui-router": "~0.2.13"
```

I'm using Mean-Stack-Relacional from here: https://github.com/jpotts18/mean-stack-relational

**EDIT 2**

I was using angular-route, so I changed to ui-router to see if the problem was solved.

**EDIT 3**

Client Route core

```
//Setting up route
angular.module('mean').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

        $stateProvider.
            state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                template: '',
                controller: 'SessionController',
                data: {
                    method: "login"
                }
            })
            .state('signin', {
                url: '/signin',
                template: '',
                controller: 'SessionController',
                data: {
                    method: "signin"
                }
            })
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                resolve: {
                    resetMap: function ($q, $location, $rootScope) {
                        $rootScope.$emit('rootScope:emit', '');
                    }
                }
            });
    }
]);
```

Comment: What version of Angular?

Comment: I think you need add the ng-app="mean" in the body to let angular know the application context

Comment: sal niro, see EDIT 1

Comment: @LeandroHoffmann if you are using 1.3 try changing your html5 config to `$locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false });`

Comment: I did your suggestion, didn't work =/

Comment: I have the tag base inside head too

Comment: What do you mean with 'I get the index.jade with download mode'? It doesn't render anything and your browser downloads the file? If so then there is probably a problem with your 'index.render' function.

Comment: If I use like tutorials:  app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {res.render('index.jade', {'root': 'app/views/'});});, the browser downloads the file, but with app.get('*', index.render); after all other routes, It render the index again, but not invoke my client routes

Comment: Sounds like the problem is all in backend

Comment: Try `res.render('index', {'root': 'app/views/'});` You've already specified that jade is the view engine

Comment: With your suggestion, my call GET /api/cameras return to index, but on server route, /api/cameras is defined before app.all('/*',....

Comment: Does `app.get('/api/cameras'` respond to both json and html? Perhaps you need to limit it to json so that `app.get('/*'` will be matched instead when you visit that url. Try commenting out the `app.get('/api/cameras'` route definition and see if that makes index.jade render correctly

Comment: Are you using ngRoute or ui.router? You usually only pick one of them.

Comment: I'm using only ui-router

Comment: Your code sample uses `$routeProvider` and has the `angular-route` package. Ui router uses `$stateProvider` instead. Please update the code samples if the code you are using is different

Comment: Sorry, I'm editing now, I was using angular-route, and changed to ui-router to see if resolve the problem, but still the same

Comment: Done, change to actual code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69257/discussion-between-leandro-hoffmann-and-scymex).

Comment: Please check if your ng-view is not inside a directive. It should be outside on the index.html page.

Comment: I change to ui-router, using ui-view, that is inside a ng-include inside index, see code above

Comment: I don't think you can have `ui-view` inside an `ng-include`, try moving it out

Comment: OOOWWW MANNN, YOU ROCK, answer to get your bounty!

Comment: Scymex, Your suggestion solved the problem, respond with your suggestion to help others and I mark as accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Scymex help me to find this issue:

For anybody who might be using Jade, here's a quick gotcha: `div(ui-view)` compiles to `<div ui-view="ui-view"></div>.` What you need is `div(ui-view="").`

So, you can have `ui-view` inside `ng-include`, but need do this trick

Font: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/679

Answer (score 2):

You're using HTML5 routes with a hashbang fallback. What that means is you want to set your server up so that requests to `/cameras/12` redirect to `/#!/cameras/12`. The server will then render your Angular application, which will detect that it wants to go to your `viewCamera` state and will rewrite the url on the client.

You can accomplish this by simply adding the following middleware to your express app:

```js
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.set('Location', '/#!' + req.path)
       .status(301)
       .send();
});
```